# How can an untrusted feature value affect the accuracy of a machine learning model?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, feature-selection, language-models

I'm building a language detector model to classify between 2 languages given text image. The input will be the image, but I have another feature that can tell somehow the language (between 0,1) confidence, so if it's 1 or near its language 1, if it's 0 or near language 2. The problem is this feature is not accurate all the time, about 20% time of its value might be wrong.

So would it be better if I added this feature or it will degrade the model accuracy?

Is there info about which model expected to perform well on such a problem? and which optimizer?

Does it need to be a deep network or a shallow one will perform well?

Comment: They are all legitimate questions. I think you should test it ... you are the one with the data.

Comment: @JesperHybel okay. but general speaking, if the extra param might be wrong sometimes, is this will affect the model badly?